# ¿Cómo cambio atributos a multiples elementos con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Tengo varios divs con la clase `.item`

```
<div class="item">00</div>
<div class="item">01</div>
<div class="item">02</div>
<div class="item">03</div>
<div class="item">04</div>
<div class="item">05</div>
```

¿Cómo puedo cambiarle un atributo a todas las clases con Javascript?

Yo se que se puede hacer con:

```
let alturaSlider = document.querySelector(".item");
alturaSlider.style.height = "auto";
```

Pero solo lo hace a la primera y lo que necesito es cambiarlo a todas.

Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Necesitas utilizar `querySelectorAll()` asi:

```js
let alturaSlider = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
alturaSlider.forEach(function(slider) {
  slider.style.height = "auto";
});
```

```html
<div class="item">00</div>
<div class="item">01</div>
<div class="item">02</div>
<div class="item">03</div>
<div class="item">04</div>
<div class="item">05</div>
```

Comment: alanfcm Muchas gracias por tu respuesta ... no sabia que forEach lo podia hacer. GRACIAS